# how to get a single database value using mysqli (php)?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to pull a single value from a database and assign it to a php variable. All of the mysqli functions appear to pull an entire row, while I want one value of that row (ex. ID, name, ect).

This is what I have so far:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM test_table WHRE ID='" . $_GET['ID'] . "'");
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  
  $test= $row['ID'];
  echo $test;
```

When I run the above I don't get any output; $test is unassigned. What is the correct command to assign a value to my $test variable?

Comment: please tell me, what is the output for var_dump($row);

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.  Never execute user input as code.

Comment: And you should add error handling to your database calls.

Comment: php array keys are case sensitive, don't forget. do a `var_dump($row)` to see what REALLY came out of the db.

Comment: Thanks guys for the tip about var_dump. Unfortunately I have to use user input as a part of the query, but the next step is I will use a stored procedure to sanitize the inputs. Just trying to get off the ground. Thanks again for your comments

Comment: @user3538411: `"Unfortunately I have to use user input as a part of the query"` - No, you don't.  You have to use it as a *value* in the query.  Currently you're using it as *executable code* in the query, which is the problem.  Using prepared statements which have value placeholders and then supplying the value separately is how you solve this problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You forgot a E in youy WHERE clause

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE ID='" . $_GET['ID'] . "'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();  
$test= $row['ID'];
echo $test;
```

If your 'ID' field is a integer, quotes are not necessary.

Comment: I think the first mistake is that @Macbenrnie!

Comment: Putting SQL-injectable code in an answer that can be copied/pasted as-is may be considered somewhat irresponsible...

Comment: thank you macberni, it is always the simple things! I swear I stared at that code for an hour and never say it! @david, thank for the reminder, I will be sure to sanitize my inputs going forward.

Comment: This answer should not be used by anyone as it is insecure/unstable.